# Using LINQ to strip a suffix from a string if it contains a suffix in a list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, string, linq-to-objects

How can I strip a suffix from a string, and return it, using C#/LINQ? Example:

```
string[] suffixes = { "Plural", "Singular", "Something", "SomethingElse" };

string myString = "DeleteItemMessagePlural";

string stringWithoutSuffix = myString.???; // what do I do here?

// stringWithoutSuffix == "DeleteItemMessage"
```

Comment: Do the suffixes overlap? Do you want to remove multiple suffixes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var firstMatchingSuffix = suffixes.Where(myString.EndsWith).FirstOrDefault();
if (firstMatchingSuffix != null)
    myString = myString.Substring(0, myString.LastIndexOf(firstMatchingSuffix));
```

Comment: +1 - what I would have done. Alternately newMyString = myString.Remove(myString.Length - suffix.Length).

Comment: FirstOrDefault() will give a null if not found and then a null exception on the following line.  Ideally if you want precisely one, use Single() and it will throw sooner (can be an issue in longer examples) and the semantics are cleaner.  You can also put the condition inside the Single(...).

Comment: you should check for null or you can just use `.First()`. If no suffix is present your code crashes a line ahead with a nasty `NullReferenceException` because `firstMatchingSuffix` is null.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a regular expression from the list:

```
var regex = new Regex("(" + String.Join("|", list.Select(Regex.Escape)) + ")$");

string stringWithoutSuffix = regex.Replace(myString, "");
```

Comment: It's "can" rather than "need", isn't it? There is always more than one way ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming there is exactly one matching suffix (this will check that)
var suffixToStrip = suffixes.Single(x => myString.EndsWith(x));

// Replace the matching one:
var stringWithoutSuffix =  Regex.Replace(myString, "(" +suffixToStrip + ")$", "");
```

OR, since you know the length of the matching suffix:

```
// Assuming there is exactly one matching suffix (this will check that)
int trim = suffixes.Single(x => myString.EndsWith(x)).Length;

// Remove the matching one:
var stringWithoutSuffix =  myString.Substring(0, myString.Length - trim);
```

Comment: You need to `Regex.Escape` `suffixToStrip`